# Is There any Javax.comm third party solution for Vista and for Freebsd?

Tags: java, windows-vista, serial-port, freebsd

I need to access the Serial Ports with Java in Windows Vista and FreebSD 
is there any third party Solution to do that?
I understand Sun doesn't have a solution for that

Comment: I want it for JDK 1.6 and FreeBSD 7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [RXTX](http://rxtx.org/) for an alternative to the Sun serial port library.